# Google AppEngine: Use SQLite file uploaded by user

Tags: sqlite, google-app-engine

I want to create this web "service":

```
HTTP REQUEST: User uploads a SQLite file

(REQUEST PROCESSING) the app reads the SQLite and perform a basic operation

HTTP RESPONSE: Stream the SQLite file back, as a download for the user.
```

Is it possible with Google AppEngine?
(feel free to suggest different method)

If not, any free hosting service where that would be possible? It is for users of an open source software, no money for hosting.

Comment: Is there any native java library for processing sqlite files?

Comment: When passing SQLite files between implementations, be sure to use INTEGER when defining columns (i.e. not any other variant form like INT, BIGINT, etc) especially on primary keys. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622582/sqllite3-update-statment-has-no-effect/6656847#6656847

Comment: Although I don't fully know what your "end-game" is, this sounds like it would be better suited to an application that your users download and run locally, rather than a webservice. As @tim suggests, sqlite files are binary and take advantage of features on the host machine therefore are not guaranteed to be portable. They can get quite large too (depending what they are used for) so uploading/download over net might be quite undesirable vs processing locally

Comment: @Chris: The end goal is to allow users to fix a known problem in a particular popular file format. It is a one-time operation. I want to give people an extremely simple way to fix their file, because most are computer newbies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but requires a bit of development:

- For in/out streaming re-use this app engine project: https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/transdeck
- Implement this small SQLJet enhancement: http://code.google.com/p/sqljet/issues/detail?id=159
- Call SQLJet from the "transdeck" servlet

Answer (score 1):

App Engine has no built-in server-side support for SQLite. I'm not aware of pure Python or Java libraries to read and write SQLite files.

Comment: There is a pure-Java SQLite implementation called SQLJet. Can I use any library I want on Google App Engine? If so, that would mean my service is doable?

Comment: @Nicolas Unless said library uses classes not on the whitelist, it will work fine. The only likely problem would be if it insists on reading from a file rather than a stream ,since you can't write files on App Engine.