# Creating a sqlite-file within appengine

Tags: java, sqlite, google-app-engine

Im struggeling with the gae filesystem restrictions.
I am creating a tool that can export a datastructur into a lot of different output-files (json, xml...)
One of them is a sqlite-database-file.
Do you have any ideas how this can be done in this restricted environment?

I tried creating an inmemory database without success:

```
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

I also tried to use the file-storage bucket:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:gs://"+bucketnameü+"/sqllite");
```

Neither of them worked. I'm afraid this is not possible at all :( I dont want to start a compute engine instance in order to create a sqllite file.

Are there any other frameworks out there that could possible create that database file on the fly.

Here the whole code:

```
Connection c = null;
            try {
              Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");           
              c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:gs://"+bucketnameü+"/sqllite");
              Statement statement = c.createStatement();
              statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  // set timeout to 30 sec.
              statement.executeUpdate("create table person (id integer, name string)");
              c.close();

            } catch ( Exception e ) {
              System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
              e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
```

I already found an interesting approach in [Google AppEngine: Use SQLite file uploaded by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871897/google-appengine-use-sqlite-file-uploaded-by-user)

I tried SQLJet with an inmemory database without success. gaevfs does not look like a good idea either.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to access the file system you can create a [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) which let you avoid much of App Engine's limitations, particularly the access to the file system.