# Flex AIR and SQLite blobs: Why 3-5 extra bytes added when storing blobs?

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, blob

I'm using Flex 4 Air (sdk 4.5) and SQLite to store blobs (png files) using this code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO pages (id, data) VALUES (:id, :data)";           
sqlStatement.text = sql;        
sqlStatement.parameters[":id"] = file.name;         
sqlStatement.parameters[":data"] = file.data;
sqlStatement.execute();
```

The table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "pages" ("id" varchar, "data" blob)
```

The problem is that the data stored has 3-5 extra bytes added to it, in the beginning of the data chunk. (If I store a 1000 bytes png, the data stored in the blob typically become 1004 bytes - confirmed by examining the SQLite file outside the Flex environment).

When reading the data back, using...

```
sql = "SELECT id, CAST(data AS ByteArray) AS data FROM pages"
```

...I have to trim the data ByteArray 3-5 bytes to get a valid image.

Clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

[What is the first bytes in a Blob column SQlite Adobe AIR? Blob Sizeinfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388456/what-is-the-first-bytes-in-a-blob-column-sqlite-adobe-air-blob-sizeinfo)

And if you're having trouble displaying them:

[Flex local SQLite BLOB display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878663/flex-local-sqlite-blob-display)

Comment: Thank you, SQLiteNoob! Aha, it seems that this is something that AIR does on it's own, without being asked for! This effectively stops me from using AIR SQLite the way I intended to. Hmfp.